# Format Crypto API date to dateString

Tags: node.js, api, date, ejs

Am making a request to CryptoCompare API, and the data is parsed to my ejs template, i want the last update object key value to be shown in my template all i get is a number(62837329), and i used new Date() function to parse the date and it gave me a very wrong date.

***How I parsed the date in my ejs template***

```
<p> <%= new Date(display.RAW.ETH.USD.LASTUPDATE) %></p>
```

*The date format that is shown in my template, if possible i wish it is in short date format*

```
Sun Jan 18 1970 15:27:56 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the CryptoCompare API is returning a timestamp in seconds from Jan 1, 1970 where the JavaScript `Date` expects a timestamp in milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970. Therefore you should multiply the number fetched by 1000.

`<p> <%= new Date(display.RAW.ETH.USD.LASTUPDATE * 1000) %></p>`

As far as formatting goes I would recommend [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) as a great way to easily format dates to your liking.

Comment: Not just your belief, it is a UNIX timestamp, which is measured in seconds. FWIW, this can be parsed directly by Moment: `moment.unix(display.RAW.ETH.USD.LASTUPDATE).format()`